# detecting when all child directives of a parent Angular directive have linked

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a clean way to detect when all child directives of a given type have been linked.  I want the parent directive to be generic so it should work regardless of whether the child elements use ng-repeat or not.  Note that ng-repeat changes the linking order.

Example 1:  The parent post-link function will be executed after all the child elements have been linked, so I can simply track each child as it is linked then process them during parent post-link.

```
<parent>
    <child></child>
    <child></child>
    <child></child>
</parent>
```

Example 2:  ng-repeat changes the linking order.  In this case, the parent post-link will have already completed before attempting to link the children.  Therefore, I can't use the parent post-link function to determine when all children have been linked, but I can add a check for $scope.$last on each child.

```
<parent>
    <child ng-repeat="c in children"></child>
</parent>
```

The problem I'm having is coming up with a nice, **clean** solution to handle both cases as it seems wrong for a parent to have to check whether the children use ng-repeat or not.  Currently what I'm doing is inserting a dummy child into the template to hold the transcluded children using ng-repeat.

```
    <child ng-transclude ng-repeat="dummy in [0]"></child>
```

That forces example 1 to act like example 2 and always generate a $scope.$last.  It appears to work but has a definite smell about it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
<parent>
    <child></child>
    <child></child>
    <child last="true"></child>
</parent>
```

Then within child directive check for `$last` or `attrs.last` and let child directive trigger event or whatever to communicate with parent

Comment: Thanks.  That's a definite improvement over the hacky method I'm using at the moment.  It still feels like there should just be some event or callback that I can hook into, though.